# default text when the input is empty in angular for label while binding

Tags: angularjs, angular, angularjs-directive, ng-bind-html, ng-bind

I have this piece of code that is working fine and displays the data as per received from controller into the binding. However, I tried to make server data as string.empty and I was expecting this default text "Your name" would appear, and it is not. I want the default text to be shown if server returns empty string.

```
<label for="name" class="label-proj" ng-bind="ctrl.name">Your name</label>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
<label for="name" class="label-proj">{{ctrl.name || "Your name"}}</label>
```

Comment: Thank you, let me try quickly and let you know, as I also want to use it in th (Table header column)

Comment: Thank you, it worked like a charm in all the places I needed :) Cheers